# MySQL Data Provider is absent in Change Data Source of VS2013

Tags: mysql, .net, visual-studio-2013, mysql-connector

I have installed last `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.8.3`

but it is absent in **Change Data Source of VS2013** so I cannot use it with `EntityFramework`.

It appears under **Change Data Source of VS2012** perfectly...

What do I am missing?

I know that I can use always  VS2012 to create EF to MySQL... But I would like see **MySQL Data Provider** in  **Change Data Source of VS2013**

Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

I did some investigation and I installed this

https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-visualstudio-plugin-1.1.1.msi

based on

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601041,601041#msg-601041

And it is appearing well!!! Hahahahaa!

[image]